# How to pass an object to controller that contains an html string in .NetCore

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have an object that I want to pass to the controller. This object contains multiple strings that contains different sections of html code. My code worked for normal strings being passed, but once I tried adding html code, it failed to route anymore and I started getting 404s.

I tried changing the model to encode the string prior to passing it across however that failed completely. The following code works if the 3 strings contain no html code within. The sample strings are what I'm trying to get passed to my controller through the ajax call.

Javascript

```
var htmlString1 = '<div style="width: 100px;">Test html div 1</div>';
var htmlString2 = '<div style="width: 100px;">Test html div 2</div>';
var htmlString3 = '<div style="width: 100px;">Test html div 3</div>';

var htmlSectionContainer = {
    htmlSection1: htmlString1,
    htmlSection2: htmlString2,
    htmlSection3: htmlString3
};

debugger;
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages")",
    method: "GET",
    data: { "data": JSON.stringify(data) },
    success: (response) => {
        //do things
    });
}
```

Model

```
public class HtmlSectionContainer
{
    //Article ids for each of the pivot section intros.
    public string htmlSection1{ get; set; }
    public string htmlSection2 { get; set; }
    public string htmlSection3 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DisplayHtmlObjects(string data)
{
    HtmlSectionContainer section = new HtmlSectionContainer();

    if (data != null)
    {
        section = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HtmlSectionContainer>(data);
    }

    return View(section);
}
```

The actual result of the above html strings is a 404.

Trying to encode the individual strings inside the object still gives me a 404.

```
var htmlSectionContainer = {
    htmlSection1: encodeURI(htmlString1),
    htmlSection2: encodeURI(htmlString2),
    htmlSection3: encodeURI(htmlString3)
};
```

Right now I'm not hitting the breakpoint at all inside the controller action. I should be able to hit the breakpoint, and in the data parameter see each of the 3 strings.

Also minor improvement, if possible, I'd prefer to have HtmlSectionContainer data as the parameter instead of string data in the controller action it data was null when I tried to do that.

Comment: I have  tried that and both are OK.404 means wrong url.Make sure the action exists with `"@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages")"`

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in this JS Code, i think it's getting the URL wrong

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages"),
    method: "GET",
    data: { "data": JSON.stringify(data) },
    success: (response) => {
        //do things
    });
}
```

It should be like this, you missed  closing " it should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages")',
    method: "GET",
    data: { "data": JSON.stringify(data) },
    success: (response) => {
        //do things
    });
}
```

I have replaces the double quotation marks " to single quotation marks '  in this line

`'@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages")'`

Because inside the string you're using double quotations and that'll lead JS to think that the string has ended here.

And also you're passing `data` object `JSON.stringify(data)` but i don't see where that variable been declared and populated, you're using the variable `htmlSectionContainer` above to set the HTML data. so i guess it should be like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages")',
    method: "GET",
    data: { "data": JSON.stringify(htmlSectionContainer) },
    success: (response) => {
        //do things
    });
}
```

Comment: Somehow I lost the closing " when I was copying the code over but I had it in my project. I tried what you suggested with the single quotes, unfortunately that doesn't actually fix the issue. I'm still getting the same 404 issue. I put both `'@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages")'` and `"@Url.Action("DisplayHtmlObjects", "Pages")"` in a variable and both of them evaluate to the correct path `/Pages/DisplayHtmlObjects` and like I said, if I don't have html code inside my strings it paths correctly. It seems to be specific to the html code inside the string.

Comment: You need to make sure that your action is reachable with that url, try it on the browser  since its `GET` or try specifying explicit url/route using `Route` attribute above your action

Comment: The action is reachable in get and if I make it my default startup action. My guess is that my encoding isn't working properly. I'm going to try replacing the string with escaped quotes instead of using the encodeURI function to see if that makes a difference. I believe that it might be trying to encode the string parameters twice and that might be causing an issue? If not, I can always work around by passing a lookup string value and just pulling the data again from the db. I just wanted to minimize calls to the db by passing html data from view to controller to another view.